# MySQL varchar has line break and a working LIKE-clause in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I have a mysql/innoDB-table where streetnames and numbers are in the same field (varchar(255)) separated by a line break.

There are many ideas out there how to put it there, but now I need to search for matching streets+numbers with the help of PHP and don't find a solution:

I want to find the field "streetfield" with the following content:

```
street
number
```

and I know the exact values for *street* and *number*

I tried it with plain SQL like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE streetfield LIKE 'street number'
```

This didn't work. I found another approach, but this didn't work es well

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE streetfield LIKE 'street'+CODE(10)+'number'
```

I tried `CODE(13)` and `CODE(10)+CODE(13)`, but without success. I can't use "%" because I need perfect matches. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you fix the storage so it is 2 fields?

Comment: unfortunately not, there is plenty of logic based on this field

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE streetfield = 'street \n number';       --- the spaces are for clarity, 
                                                 --- should be removed
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE streetfield = CONCAT('street', CHAR(10), 'number');
```

Use:

```
CHAR(10)   for   \n
CHAR(13)   for   \r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE streetfield LIKE 'street\nnumber';
```

Comment: @ypercube: MySQL uses the C escape syntax inside strings, it needs double the slashes. :)

Comment: You don't want to escape the backslash but the newline.

Comment: @ypercube: Hmm... the backslash would be '\\\\', do you see what I mean?

Comment: Doesn't work. One backslash does. Unless you meant to use that as a whole query in PHP in double quotes?